# Pandas IndexSlice fails with pd.style

Tags: python, pandas

Given this dataframe:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),
                          index=['A','B','C','All'],
                          columns=[2011,2012,2013,'All']).round(2)
        print(df)
Out[1]:

     2011  2012  2013   All
A    0.94  0.17  0.06  0.64
B    0.49  0.16  0.43  0.64
C    0.16  0.20  0.22  0.37
All  0.94  0.04  0.72  0.18
```

I'm trying to using `pd.style` to format the output of a dataframe. One keyword is `subset` where you define where to apply your formatting rules (for example: highlight max). The documentation for [pd.style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Slicing) hints that it's better to use `pd.IndexSlice` for this:

> The value passed to `subset` behaves simlar to slicing a DataFrame.
>
> - A scalar is treated as a column label
> - A list (or series or numpy array)
> - A tuple is treated as (row_indexer, column_indexer)
>
> Consider using `pd.IndexSlice` to construct the tuple for the last one.

I'm trying to understand why it's failing in some cases.

Let's say I want to to apply a bar to all rows but the first and last, and all columns but the last.

This `IndexSlice` works:

```
In [2]: df.ix[pd.IndexSlice[1:-1,:-1]]
Out[2]:
   2011  2012  2013
B  0.49  0.16  0.43
C  0.16  0.20  0.22
```

But when passed to `style.bar`, it doesn't:

```
In [3]: df.style.bar(subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:-1,:-1], color='#d65f5f')

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'>
with these indexers [1] of <class 'int'>
```

Whereas if I pass it slightly differently, it works:

```
In [4]: df.style.bar(subset=pd.IndexSlice[df.index[1:-1],df.columns[:-1]],
                     color='#d65f5f')
```

[image: df.style.bar works as expected]

I'm confused why this doesn't work. There seems to be a bit of lack of documentation regarding `pd.IndexSlice` so maybe I'm missing something. It could also be a bug in `pd.style` (which is fairly new, since `0.17.1` only).

Can someone explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's too bad this compatibility issue exists. From what I can tell though, you answer your own question. From you doc's you included the line:

> A tuple is treated as (row_indexer, column_indexer)

This is not what we get with the first slice:

```
In [1]: pd.IndexSlice[1:-1,:-1]
Out[2]: (slice(1, -1, None), slice(None, -1, None))
```

but we do get something of that form from the second slice method:

```
In [3]: pd.IndexSlice[df.index[1:-1],df.columns[:-1]]
Out[4]: (Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object'), Index([2011, 2012, 2013], dtype='object'))
```

I don't think that `pd.IndexSlice` even does anything except wrap the contents in a tuple for this second case. You can just do this:

```
df.style.bar(subset=(df.index[1:-1],df.columns[:-1]),
                     color='#d65f5f')
```